# PHPmailer send copy to email address in a form

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on editing a site which has been built using some strange Smarty system, template TPL files and a load of JS and PHP.

I have a Classes in PHP files which sends and email to an array of email address from a differnt PHP file.

I'm wanted to add to this array so it sends a copy of the email to the person who filled in the form.

The array of recipents is:

```
  //target email address settings
  $this->settings['mailer_address_booknow'] = array('ADDRESS@ADDRESS.com', 'ADDRESS@ADDRESS.com', 'ADDRESS@ADDRESS.com', 'james@bernhardmedia.com');
```

And the sending PHP file is:

```
  public function SendEmail( $email_address_array, $email_data, $subject,   $template, &$send_message ) {

      $smartyObj = Configurator::getInstance()->smarty; 
      $send_message = '';
      $send_result = 0;

      try { 

        $mail = new PHPMailer( true );      
        $mail->IsSMTP( true );  
        $mail->SMTPDebug = false;
        $mail->IsHTML( true );
        $mail->Host = Configurator::getInstance()->getSettings( "phpmailer_smtp" ); 
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        for( $x = 0;$x < sizeof($email_address_array);$x++ ){
            $mail->AddAddress( trim($email_address_array[$x]) );
        }           
        $smartyObj->assign( 'email_data', $email_data );
        $mail->SetFrom( 'info@forexchange.co.uk', 'Forexchange Currency Order');



        $mail->Subject  = $subject;
        $mail->Body     = $smartyObj->fetch( $template );                       
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
        } else {
            $send_result = 1;
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $send_message = $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $send_message = $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
    //echo $send_result;
    //exit;
    return $send_result;
}
```

The form is on the home page of this site - http://www.forexchange.co.uk/

Please help, I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Smarty I think refers to the Smarty template Engine for php see [here](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/)

Append the email address to the array `$email_address_array`

When you call the method

`SendEmail( $email_address_array, $email_data, $subject,   $template, &$send_message );`

either append the email to that data set (`$email_address_array`) before you call it or append it inline ( in the call)

Can you show how you call it?

EDIT
If your data is stored in

`$this->settings['mailer_address_booknow'];`

add that to the call,

```
SendEmail( $this->settings['mailer_address_booknow'] , $email_data, $subject, $template, &$send_message );
```

if you need to add to that array then do this before calling it

`$this->settings['mailer_address_booknow'] = "ADDED_EMAIL";`

Comment: Hi Yeeoow, THanks for look at this. The Smarty is the template system and seems to work fine. This is the array of email address: //target email address settings
    $this->settings['mailer_address_booknow'] = array('address@address.com', 'address@address.com', 'address@address.com', 'james@bernhardmedia.com');

Comment: I think I might need to Split up the $email_data to find the email address then add it to a varable then add it to the array i sent before - does that make sense?

Comment: If that is the data then call it like so SendEmail(  $this->settings['mailer_address_booknow'] , $email_data, $subject,   $template, &$send_message );  update your answer to show how you call it

Comment: Thanks Yeeoow, The email address array is in $email_address_array but I need to add the email address which one of the the lines in $email_data. I was hoping i could do something like $this->settings['mailer_address_booknow'] = array(', 'james@bernhardmedia.com', $email_data[4] ); but thats not working!

Comment: So I can understand, you need to you need to take an email address from $email_address_array and OVERWRITE a part of $email_data ?